# Submit an HTML form and solve captcha via Python

Tags: python, html, forms

It is possible to submit an HTML form through Python and then validate a captcha on the page after submitting the form?
Where I can start?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: You can't (or shouldn't be able to) write a script to solve a captcha. That's the whole point.

Comment: Captcha's are designed specifically to prevent this :) If you can break it kudos to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous. If what you want to do is make a python script fill up an HTML form somewhere online and then fill in the captcha as well, then it shouldn't be possible. That is the whole point of a captcha, to prevent bots and scripts from spamming forms.

But instead if what you mean is that you want to use python to validate an HTML form you have made to use somewhere then you should look into some python backend frameworks like Django or Flask. With these frameworks you can connect front end HTML,CSS,JS etc. to backend logic and have validation for custom forms and use captchas and stuff.